# When translating SQL to relational algebra, how do you represent the symbol *?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

```
SELECT F.PNAME, SUM(F.QTY)                              
FROM (SELECT P.*, S.QTY
      FROM (SELECT PNUM, PNAME 
            FROM PARTS) P,
                (SELECT PNUM, QTY 
                 FROM SHIPMENTS) S 
      WHERE P.PNUM = S.PNUM) F
GROUP BY F.PNAME
```

Notice there's a P.*
I don't think π with a subscript of (P.*, s.qty) is legal in relational algebra. How would I go about this?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please give a reference to the version of relational algebra you are supposed to use.

Answer (score 3):

You don't.

The relational algebra doesn't have any concept of namespacing; it has no awareness that `P.FOO` and `P.BAR` have anything in common. (In fact, the usual practice, when writing relational algebra, is to omit the `P.`. If this would cause any naming conflicts, then the "rename" operation, *ρ*, is used to rename attributes as necessary, e.g. to `P_FOO` and `P_BAR`.)